# Batch size and number of epochs in partial_fit in SkLearn SGDRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand the way we can implement partial_fit. I have created a dummy dataset with make_regression. Further, I am partial fitting the X and y with partial_fit method.  Can you please where do I mention the batch size and the number of epochs?

For example, if I want to use the batch size of 2000 records and 10 epochs to get the model trained in an incremental way on the full dataset.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor


X,y=make_regression(n_samples=20000, n_features=5, random_state=0, noise=4.0,bias=100.0)


reg=SGDRegressor(max_iter=1000)
reg.partial_fit(X,y)
print(reg.score(X,y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply pass the features and labels for your minibatch to partial_fit in the same way that you would use fit:

```
reg.partial_fit(X_minibatch, y_minibatch)
```

Below is a piece of code for showing how to do:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
 
def iter_minibatches(chunksize):
    # Provide chunks one by one
    chunkstartmarker = 0
    while chunkstartmarker < numtrainingpoints:
        chunkrows = range(chunkstartmarker,chunkstartmarker+chunksize)
        X_chunk, y_chunk = getrows(chunkrows)
        yield X_chunk, y_chunk
        chunkstartmarker += chunksize
 
def main():
    batcherator = iter_minibatches(chunksize=1000)
    model = SGDRegressor()
 
    for X_chunk, y_chunk in batcherator:
        model.partial_fit(X_chunk, y_chunk)
 
    y_predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Does it mean that I need to create the subset of the full dataset manually with code first?I thought if we provide the batch size then in background the shuffled batches will be created.